# UPDATE statement is not updating results in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update result in SQL server with below query but its not updating. If i write (update lunTime set lunOut = '2014-12-08 23:23:23.120' where empName='Mike' and 
date='2014-12-08') it is updating it.

```
protected void btnLunOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(
       "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=MY_Srv;Integrated Security=True");

    conn1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     "Update [lunTime] SET lunOut = @LunOUT where (empName=@EmpName and date=@Date)", 
     conn1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", drpDwnEmp.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LunOUT", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn1.Close();

    drpDwnEmp.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: select * from [lunTime] where empName=@EmpName and date=@Date.
check if you are getting record by passing same value

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it simple does not find the record for `data == DateTime.Now` case.

It is unlclear what you want to achieve, but maybe some range conditions on `date` variable or `Now.Date` is the solution (assuming `date` is actually date only, no time portion):

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.Date);
```